# How to convert bytes to Xsd Schema in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xsd-validation

i am actually trying to convert the bytes stream Xsd file into Xsd Schema but was unable to do it through the below code

```
            Stream streamXsdd = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(path + "\\input.xsd"));
            XmlSchema xsdDoc = new XmlSchema();
            xsdDoc.Write(streamXsdd); OR Read(streamXsdd,validationeventhandler);  
// i thought the above are used for conversion but they are not.

            XmlSchemaSet tempSchemaDocs = new XmlSchemaSet();
            tempSchemaDocs.Add(xsdDoc);
```

but above does not convert it. Is there any other way to do it ?

Comment: Are you _sure_ it has been serialized as _binary_ not _text_ (as I would be expecting) ?

Comment: Unrelated: I suggest using [`Path.Combine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=net-6.0).

Comment: actually i am getting the Xsd file form AWS S3 in bytes and then have to validate it with xml as well.

Comment: `xsdDoc.Write(streamXsdd); OR Read(streamXsdd,validationeventhandler);` - which one? You surely want to _read_ the xsd.

Comment: actually i want to just convert to xsd schema file and add it to the schemaset .. used both of these but does not look like they are used for conversion.

Comment: Yes, you always get bytes. That's the language computers speak. But it's up to you how to interpret these bytes. So it makes a difference if you say "bytes are bytes" or "bytes are chars in XYZ encoding". So, first thing I'd be checking would be how the files are stored to AWS S3. And my first _guess_ would be they are utf-16 or utf-8 encoded.

Answer (score 1):

The docs suggest you would want to use `XmlSchema.Read`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.schema.xmlschema.read?view=net-6.0#system-xml-schema-xmlschema-read(system-io-stream-system-xml-schema-validationeventhandler)

However this is a static method on `XmlSchema` so your code would change to be more like

```cs
Stream streamXsdd = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(path + "\\input.xsd"));
XmlSchema xsdDoc = XmlSchema.Read(streamXsddd, validationeventhandler);

XmlSchemaSet tempSchemaDocs = new XmlSchemaSet();
tempSchemaDocs.Add(xsdDoc);
```

Could it be that your `Read` wasn't working because you were effectively discarding the result, as it returns a new instance, rather than populating an existing one?